# Can not find symbol with Maven compile includes tag and Lombok annotation

Tags: java, maven, lombok

I have a maven project with multiple maven modules. Some classes are annotated with lombok annotations. I try to package jar files with only a subset of classes. My maven compile configuration looks like this.
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/include-exclude.html

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2</version>
  <configuration>
    <includes>
      <include>**/package_a/*</include>
    </includes>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And I see the following error message, where XXX.java is not part of package_a. But methods of XXX.java are called in some class from package_a:

```
[ERROR] C:/..src dir../XXX.java :[123,45] cannot find symbol. 
[ERROR] symbol:   method [setter name here]
```

I tried to create jar of another package `<include>**/package_b/*</include>`, where Package_b neither includes classes with lombok annotations, nor refers to classes with them. And this is successful. So I am guessing if this may related with lombok behavior. Compile is somehow based on raw java files, because delombok only happens on java files included in compile plugin. Does lombok compatible with compile plugin includes tag?

I have tried following workaround and code is able to compile with both. However, the compile all takes longer than expected.

1. Remove the includes tag in maven compile plugin. Thus, all classes are compiled.
2. Delombok in child module as follows. Keeps `includes` tag in maven compile plugin.
   http://anthonywhitford.com/lombok.maven/lombok-maven-plugin/usage.html

```
<sourceDirectory>target/generated-sources/delombok</sourceDirectory>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.18.10.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
          <goals>
            <goal>delombok</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```